# Why does Blender 3.6 not save addon preferences?

Tags: add-on, customization, startup-file

I unchecked several addons that I dont use and checked otehrs that I need, and theres checkbox Automatic save preferences, yet, it`s all the same after the next launch

Comment: It should work as is, and it works for me on Blender v3.6.5. Try on that version, if it still doesn't work please use the menu Help > Report A Bug.

Comment: Could you tell us what OS you are on, and whether there's anything unconventional about your installation?

Comment: it`s windows,  unconventional may be that I have it installed on D drive, though addons and most files still are in the App data folder. I just thought that if I install it on D drive I would save memory on the C drive, but most of the Blender size is still there on C. Anyway it worked on previous versions